# Set same width and height of tiles in ggplot2 for different plots

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have several data sets with three variables x, y and z. I want to display these with geom_tile.

For example:

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(
  x = factor(rep(c(2, 5, 7, 9, 12), 2)),
  y = rep(c(1, 2), each = 5),
  z = factor(rep(1:5, each = 2))
)

ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = z), colour = "grey50", width = 1)
```

The data sets can have different numbers of values in all three variables.

Next example:

```
df2 <- df[1:3,]

ggplot(df2, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = z), colour = "grey50", width = 1)
```

As you can see, as there are less tiles now, they are also bigger. However, I want the tiles in all plots to have the same size (for example in cm). What I do NOT want: to merge the plots in any way in one graphic, they even end up in different documents. I also do not really want to save the plots first and load the files into my (markdown) documents.

Comment: Have you tried `facet_grid`? What does your expected output look like?

Comment: I want individual plots, not facets. The individual plots can then also have different widths and heights in total.

Comment: Not sure if it's what you're looking for, but you can also use `theme(aspect.ratio = 1)` or `coord_fixed()`. Another way would be to set the same y-axis limits for every plot.

Comment: `coord_fixed()` is at least quite OK, thank you! But the tiles do not have totally the same size. I want the tiles have exactly the same size in both plots (like in cm or inch)

Answer (score 0):

What about a boilerplate which is fed with data afterwards?

```
template <- ggplot() + 
  geom_tile(aes(x, y)) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 10)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 10)) +
  scale_size_identity()

d <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 1:10)
```

```
template %+% d
```

[image: many tiles]

```
template %+% d[1,]
```

[image: few tiles]

Remember to set identical image sizes when `ggsave`ing.

Comment: Thank you, but I would like to have plots with different sizes